# Constraint that value in foreign row matches another value?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

```
// table_a
{
    "id": "aaa",
    "name": "abc"
}
// table_b
{
    "id": "bbb",
    "firstName": "abc"
}
//table_c
{
    "table_a_id": "aaa",
    "table_b_id": "bbb"
}

// constraint - table_a name matches table_b firstName
```

Comment: To have foreign keys, you first need to have primary keys, or at least candidate keys. Your example does not clearly tell us what are the keys of each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a foreign key constraint.  Or a constraint that can be implemented using triggers.

As a foreign key constraint, you need to store the name in `c`.  In pseudo-code, this looks like:

```
create table a (
    id primary key,
    name,
    unique (name, id)
);

create table b (
    id primary key,
    firstname,
    unique (namename, id)
);

create table c (
    table_a_id references a(id),
    table_b_id references b(id),
    name,
    foreign key c_a_name_id (name, id) references (name, id),
    foreign key c_b_name_id (name, id) references (firstname, id),
);
```

The names are necessarily the same because the name is stored in `c` only once.